# Enable form submit button when classes have been removed

Tags: javascript

I have a form where the submit button is disabled when the page is loaded.

```
window.onload=function()
{
    document.getElementById('form_submit').disabled = true;
}
```

When the are empty or incorrect fields the following classes are added to the input fields:

```
if(document.getElementById('thickness').value == false)
{
    document.getElementById('div_thickness').className = "form-group has-warning";
}
else if(document.getElementById('thickness').value > 1 && document.getElementById('thickness').value < 7)
{
    document.getElementById('div_thickness').className = "form-group has-success";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('div_thickness').className = "form-group has-error";
}
```

When all error or warning classes have been removed the submit should be enabled again but the button stays disabled. Is there any conflict I am missing?

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('has-error') || document.getElementsByClassName('has-warning'))
{
    document.getElementById('form_submit').disabled = true;
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('form_submit').disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query for the elements, an empty array is returned, so there is something. You need to check for the array length  :

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('has-error').length > 0 || document.getElementsByClassName('has-warning').length > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
    else if(document.getElementById('thickness').value > 1 && document.getElementById('thickness').value < 7)
    {
        document.getElementById('div_thickness').className = "form-group has-success";
    if(document.getElementById("#div_thikness").classList.contain('form-group has-error'){
    $document.getElementById('#div_thickness).classList.remove('has-error);
    }
 if(document.getElementById("#div_thikness").classList.contain('form-group has-warning'){
    $document.getElementById('#div_thickness).classList.remove('has-warning);
    }
    }​
```

update the above code when success you have to remove has-warning and has-error class not only add the has-success.